# How to do "realistic" plastic material?

Tags: unity, shaders, materials

How can i do "realistic" plastic material in Unity 3d , using standard shader or other shader ?

Can you suggest me options ?

Thanks

Comment: "Realistic" is one of those terms that gets abused a lot in games. ;) This question could be improved by describing the specific traits of plastic you want — possibly with image examples of the kind of plastic you're trying to mimic (since "plastic" covers everything from dull & milky polypropylene to glossy ABS or polycarbonate), and examples of your best in-engine attempts so far, detailing what about them you want to change.

Answer (score 2):

Use a standard shader for simple materials. If you are looking how to modify the standard shader to achieve a plastic-y effect, consult the [documentation on material effects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialCharts.html).

On the site it says that

> There are also hints on how to make realistic materials in these charts. In essence it is about choosing a workflow (default or metallic) and obtaining relevant values for your maps or colour pickers. For instance, if we wanted to make shiny white plastic, we would want a white Albedo. Since it is not a metal we would want a dark Specular (or a very low Metallic value) and finally a very high Smoothness.

For more specific effects, you may need to make your own shaders.

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing some example settings for the standard shader which result in a "plastic" look.

Comment: Sorry, thought info was easily found on link provided. Editing now.

Comment: Links are good, but answers should not rely on them for answering the question. When Unity reorganizes the URLs for their documentation again, your link will break and your answer will not be very helpful for future visitors.